# Code Comprehension Issue

Tags: java

So I had a problem where I had to sort players based off of their score and rank them. My solution was a simple quicksort in descending order. However, my teachers provided a solution is a little bit different and I honestly don't really understand it.

If anyone could help me get a grasp on this so I can understand and program better solutions in the future I would appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class DraftKingsTwo {

    //will create an array of player objects
    final static Player[] input = {new Player("Solomon",44),new Player("Jason",42)
            ,new Player("Errol",42),new Player("Garry",41),new Player("Bernard",41),new Player("Barry",41),
    new Player("Stephen",39)};

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //will get the length of the global array
        int len = input.length;

        //creates a new map from a string to an int array
        Map<String, int[]> map = new TreeMap<>((a, b) -> b.compareTo(a));
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //string to hold the key which is the score value
            String key = Integer.toString(input[i].getScore());
            int[] arr;
            if ((arr = map.get(key)) == null){
               arr = new int[]{i, 0};
            }
            arr[1]++;
            map.put(key, arr);
        }
        int[][] groups = map.values().toArray(new int[map.size()][]);

       // standardRanking(len, groups);
        denseRanking(len, groups);

    }

        private static void denseRanking(int len, int[][] groups) {
        System.out.println("\nDense ranking");
        for (int i = 0, rank = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (rank < groups.length && i == groups[rank][0])
                rank++;
            System.out.printf("Rank of player is: %d\n%s%n\n", rank, input[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not ask your teachers?

Comment: Where's your question? It is unclear what part you are having difficulty with.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding his solution and if my teacher was available. I would ask him of course

Comment: welp this is a warm welcom to so, a swift down vote of my question and here i thought I could come to my fellow programmers for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Here is my code".
Is this your code or your teacher's code?

Your teacher sucks at commenting if it is.

First, the code fills in a map of Score to array of int.

The first element of the array is the first player index to get that score.

The second element of the array is the number of players with that score.

The map will end up like this:

```
{
    "44": [0, 1],  // player 0 got 44.  only one player.
    "42": [1, 2],  // player 1 is the first to get 42, 2 players got 42.
    "41": [3, 3],  // Player 3 is the first to get 41, 3 players got 41
    "39": [6, 1],  // Player 6 got 39, only one player.
}
```

Storing the score in the treemap as a string is a bug.  The score of "7" will rank higher than the score of "60" because of that.

The "Groups" are then extracted from the treemap:

```
[[0,1],[1,2],[3,3],[6,1]]
```

Then, the denseRanking function iterates over the list of users (which must be in order sorted by score or else this will all fail).

The denseRanking function increments the rank whenever it sees that the first element in the array matches the current player index (i == groups[rank][0]) .

The second element in the array, the number of players with that score, is unused.

I really hope this is not your teacher's code, because it is really super complicated for what it is achieving.